# How to use promise all in lodash forEach and resolve it and do res.send(data)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node.js. I doing save operation using lodash forEach. Now the problem is res.send() is executing multiple times which throws error like headers can't set after they are send.

I heard about PromiseAll but I dont know how to implement it. I read documentation but i think i am doing something wrong. It would be really helpful if someone could help.

```
_.forEach(req.body ,function(value){
  gridObj.save(value)
    .then((results) => {
      var data = {
        status: 200,
        message: 'Record save successfully ',
        data: results,
      };
      console.log(`data saved successfully ${JSON.stringify(results)}`);
      res.send(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`error in save ${error}`);
      res.send(error);
    })
});
```

I expect that the data will get stored one by one in mongoDb. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Object.entries` instead of `_.forEach` and `.map` to an array of promises, you can use `Promise.all` on that:

```
 Promise.all(
   Object.entries(req.body).map(value => gridObj.save(value))
 ).then(/*..*/).catch(/*...*/)
```

Comment: i have array of objects in req.body so i changed Object to Array but still doesnt work